# mavros missing on kinetic?

Tags: ros, installation, ros-kinetic, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was using mavros on Indigo and cannot manage to install again on kinetic.
The package does not show up in the list of `ros-kinetic-*` packages.

I additionally tried to install it manually, following the instructions on this page:
https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation

However, when replacing my distro from jade to kinetic in the following command line:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
```

I get the following error: `E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-control-toolbox`

I could not find the package in the list of `ros-kinetic-*` packages and I made sure to update my system and upgrade it.
Has anyone managed to install mavros on kinetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236585/mavros-missing-on-kinetic?/) by [Audren Cloitre](https://answers.ros.org/users/21522/audren-cloitre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems at least the packages [in this page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=mavros) are already build and their binaries are available already on Kinetic. Have you run `apt-get update`?

Also, Jade and Kinetic are not meant to work on the same Ubuntu distro. See REP-0003 for the supported hosts:

- [Jade](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#jade-turtle-may-2015-may-2017)
- [Kinetic](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Audren Cloitre](https://answers.ros.org/users/21522/audren-cloitre/) on 2016-06-09**:
Thank you 130s for your answer.
I found my mistake. I tried to install two distros of ROS to access older packages but did not readjust my sources.list and keys. After setting these for kinetic, I was able to access the package without problem.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-06-09**:
Glad to help, usually upvote is what shows the others that an answer was helpful ;)

**Comment by [Audren Cloitre](https://answers.ros.org/users/21522/audren-cloitre/) on 2016-06-10**:
Fixed! And thanks for pointing it out.